# Mvc dropdownlist default value and placeholder

Tags: text, model-view-controller, drop-down-menu, default, placeholder

I have a html.dropdownlist which have 4 options. I want it to display a placeholder text a defaut which is not included in the options. I implemented a similar thing with adding a default option to the list, however selected default option is causing div to expand and it distrups the page layout.

```
<div style="float:left; padding-left:13.4%;">
                        @Html.DropDownList("Adults", ViewData["Adults"] as List<SelectListItem>, new { @class = "dropdown2"})
</div>
```

And that is the controller code;

```
   List<SelectListItem> adt = new List<SelectListItem>();

        //adt.Add(new SelectListItem
        //{
        //    Text = "1",
        //    Value = "1"
        //});
        adt.Add(new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = "1",
            Value = "1"
        });
        adt.Add(new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = "2",
            Value = "2"
        });
        adt.Add(new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = "3",
            Value = "3"
        });
        adt.Add(new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = "4",
            Value = "4"
        });

        ViewData["Adults"] = adt;
        return View();
```

Im new with mvc and any contribution will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Adding placeholder text when its not directly implemented is tricky if not impossible. I recommend using Chosen (JQuery Plugin) instead. It is very easy to use and makes the dropdown beautiful.

https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

Example of a dropdown with chosen:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Example, Model.Example, new { @class = "chosen", data_placeholder="Choose items"})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add jquery code to add option to the dropdownlist with the select attribute so the option will be set as a placeholder:

```js
$('#selectid').append($('<option/>', { 
        value: value,
        text : value 
    }));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='selectid'>
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
    <option value="hurr">Durr</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ASP.NET MVC 5 then you can use overloaded method of `@Html.DropDownList`
with perameter type `string optionLabel`.

which will add a new option in select list at first index. will be default selected. and if your default options always selected then no need for placeholder.

```
@Html.DropDownList("Adults", ViewData["Adults"] as List<SelectListItem>, "Select Adult",new { @class = "dropdown2"})
```